# In .htaccess, how to redirect non-lowercase versions of hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In `.htaccess` on Apache2, how do you redirect all capitalization variations of a hostname to a canonical lowercase version, via 301 redirect, and keeping the rest of the path unharmed. Subdomains (or not) should do the same as well.

Additionally, accessing via an IP should *not* redirect.

examples:

- `http://Example.com/foo` => `http://example.com/foo`
- `http://A.example.com/foo` => `http://a.example.com/foo`
- `http://A.EXample.com/foo?bar` => `http://a.example.com/foo?bar`
- `http://208.67.222.222/foo` => `http://208.67.222.222/foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Make sure hostname is lowercase only (or an IP address)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[\d\.]{7,15}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Keep mind mind that every search engine worth mentioning already does this canonicalization for you. Unless you have serious problems with this, it's not generally going to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and been unable to find a solution online that encompasses any number of domains. The use-case for me is that I work on localhost, and so the first line (with example.com) will not work on both localhost and my domain, and any other name someone uses instead of localhost.

To add to @philfreo 's answer, therefore: (copying the lines but modifying only the first one)

```
# Make sure hostname is lowercase only (or an IP address)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+\.)?(.+)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[\d\.]{7,15}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Props to philfreo! Much time saved with his response.

Paragon