# Convert url to lower case using htaccess except query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string, lowercase

Am struggling with a htaccess problem.

I need to convert all the URLs from uppercase to lowercase. But the query string alone should be the same.

For example,

```
www.tESTUrl.com/sOMePath/?q=SomeStringHere
```

should be converted as,

```
www.testurl.com/somepath/?q=SomeStringHere
```

Please help to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First You have to add this to your httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then paste the below code into your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

This code redirct the url like from

`www.tESTUrl.com/sOMePath/?q=SomeStringHere`

to   `www.testurl.com/somepath/?q=SomeStringHere`

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` do not contain the domain name, only the URL path.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add this line in your `httpd.conf` to define a `RewriteMap` for handling lower case conversion:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then add this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z]+.*)$ /${lc:$1} [L,NE,R=302]
```

This will not affect `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava.. Please let me know where should I exactly place the RewriteMap ?? Sorry I am new to it.

Comment: It can be placed at the bottom of `httd.conf`. You will need to restart Apache after that change.

Comment: Let me check it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry anubhava its not working.. I am using xampp.. Windows OS.. Anything else should I do..?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding this line? This is properly tested rule and working on my side.

Comment: Yes I restarted.. Can you please tel me whether I need to enclose the RewriteMap code in any <ifmodule> tag like that..?

Comment: no it doesn't need any `<ifmodule>` block. I just placed `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` as the very last line in my `httpd.conf` and restarted. Then I placed rewrite rule in my root .htaccess and it worked. Do you have other rules also in your .htaccess?

Comment: No.. htaccess is empty

Comment: First verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes I checked it.. Its enabled.. When I am adding some garbage text its showing error..

Comment: @anubhava Ya working this code for me, but it removes the subfolder name too like "sOMePath". plz check it

Comment: That is not being done using this redirect rule. You may have some other rules doing this subfolder removal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe tweaking [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161059/in-htaccess-how-to-redirect-non-lowercase-versions-of-hostname/7897361#7897361) can handle the `www.tESTUrl.com/` hostname part of the equation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+\.)?(.+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And then I believe this should work for the `sOMePath/` path:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*)/?(.*)$ ${lc:$1}/?q=$2 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].* [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}?${QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]
```

The second line is not necessary but helpful if you want to lowercase the query string in the future. I just put this here to be complete.

You have to add this to your httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Comment: Can you please tel me whether I need to enclose the RewriteMap code in any <ifmodule> tag like that..?

Comment: You can put it in the VirtualHost entry: "<VirtualHost *>

  RewriteMap lc int:tolower" ....